# How to appropriately override equals(Object o) while using jackson mapping

Tags: java, json, jackson, equals

***JSON***  :

```
"ABCD": [  
      {  
        "xyz": 3,  
        "abc": 4,  
        "date": {  
          "start": 1462341600000,  
          "stop": 1462513680000  
        }
      }
      ...similar sub parts
    ]
```

***Datatype*** defined : I have tried to define a corresponding datatype for the json as follows [Ignoring other field as of now] :

```
public class Test {
    TestDate testDate = new TestDate();
    private Long start = testDate.startTime;
    private Long stop  = testDate.expiryTime;

    public class TestDate {
        private Long startTime;
        private Long expiryTime;
        // getter and setter implemented here 
    }
}
```

Now, what I am confused with is how to override the `equals` method to suffice the check for **start** and **stop** parameters of the JSON.

***Case 1 :*** Comparing the variables `start` and `stop` declared inside the Test class and assigned with TestDate corresponding parameters. As in :

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Test test = (Test) o;
        // Below is what I am concerned about
        if (stop != null ? !stop.equals(test.stop) : test.stop != null) return false;
        if (start != null ? !start.equals(test.start) : test.start != null) return false;
    }
```

OR

***Case 2 :*** Simply use the object `testDate` created within the Test class for comparison. As in :

```
if (testDate != null ? !testDate.equals(test.testDate) : test.testDate != null) return false;
```

***Doubts*** :

- Does the *Case 2* even suffice the *Case 1*?
- If not, whats the difference?
- If yes, which one of these is a better practice?

Looking for more stats to why use Case 2 over Case 1 in terms on code complexities and re-usability.

Comment: Case 2 does suffice case 1 - but only if the same logic re start/stop is moved to a TestDate.equals() method. I am assuming that is implicit in your Case 2.

Comment: Why do you want to override equals? Note that if you do so you will also have to override hashCode... Generally I try to avoid overriding these methods because it's hard to get right and makes code harder to maintain.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster :  I have overriden `hashCode` as well. And there is no constructor, `TestDate` is a class itself

Comment: Oops! Monday morning I guess :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct approach would be to let `Test` concern itself with its own fields, so it should be checking itself against `o` as you have done but in my opinion the `start`/`stop` fields shouldn't exist. After the `o` checks, your `Test` equals method should end with identity/null checks for `testDate` and if both are non null and not the same object then it should delegate to (and return) an equals implementation on the TestDate class.

So basically *Case 2* is the correct approach but I'd rethink the existence of start and stop on Test. Also that Case 2 statement could easily be refactored to a simple return without the if - not sure I've ever seen a ternary ? as an if condition before ;). Horses for courses but I think the following is easier to read:

```
return (testDate == test.testDate) || (testDate != null && testDate.equals(test.testDate));
```

Having the `start`/`stop` fields on the `Test` class means that the implementation of `TestDate` is leaking into the `Test` class. if you decided to make some significant change to `TestDate` (perhaps storing the values as localised dates instead for the sake of argument) then you break the `Test` class under Case 1 but Case 2 would survive this so Case 2 is more robust.

Another consideration as well is the `hashCode` method - the problems above under Case 1 with the `start`/`stop` fields on `Test` are effectively doubled because you should really be implementing `hashCode` in a consistent manner.

As systems get more complex the time involved fixing issues such as this quickly becomes non-trivial and more prone to error.

Comment: Though I get the context of your answer. Still looking for more stats to support it. As in why use Case 2 over Case 1 in terms on code complexities and re-usability.

Comment: Not sure what you are after in terms of stats - ultimately this is a subjective view. The reason that I believe Case 2 is better is to do with encapsulation and separation of concerns. Having the start/stop fields on the Test class means that the implementation of TestDate is leaking into the Test class. if you decided to make some significant change to TestDate (perhaps storing the values as localised dates instead for the sake of argument) then you break the Test class under Case 1 but Case 2 would survive this so Case 2 is more robust.

Comment: ... As systems get more complex the time involved fixing issues such as this quickly becomes non-trivial and more prone to error.

Comment: Comments above added as part of answer.